# Can't get data from data source factory when using Paging library in android

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata, android-paging

I already did all the competent of the paging library tried to send all data to the UI following [this artricle](https://medium.com/@sharmadhiraj.np/android-paging-library-step-by-step-implementation-guide-75417753d9b9) but no luck on getting the data here is my code

When I debugged I found the following:
when it's loading the network state and `pagedUserList` get notified for the first time and when the request DONE only the network `state` get notified and the list doesn't get notified with the list itself and I don't know why? any clue?

**MainActivity**

```
    private fun initAdapter() {
    newsListAdapter = NewsListAdapter { mainViewModel.retry() }
    binder.rvUsers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    binder.rvUsers.adapter = newsListAdapter
    mainViewModel.getPagedList().observe(this, Observer {
        newsListAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
}

private fun initState() {
    binder.txtError.setOnClickListener { mainViewModel.retry() }
    mainViewModel.getState().observe(this, Observer { state ->
        binder.progressBar.visibility =
            if (mainViewModel.listIsEmpty() && state == State.LOADING) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        binder.txtError.visibility =
            if (mainViewModel.listIsEmpty() && state == State.ERROR) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        if (!mainViewModel.listIsEmpty()) {
            newsListAdapter.setState(state ?: State.DONE)
        }
    })
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
  private var pagedUserList: LiveData<PagedList<User>>
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private val pageSize = 10
private val usersDataSourceFactory: UsersDataSourceFactory

init {

    usersDataSourceFactory = UsersDataSourceFactory(usersService, compositeDisposable)
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setPageSize(pageSize)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(pageSize * 3)
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .build()
    pagedUserList = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, User>(usersDataSourceFactory, config)
        .build();

}

fun getState(): LiveData<State> = Transformations.switchMap<UsersDataSource,
        State>(usersDataSourceFactory.getUserLiveData(), UsersDataSource::state)

fun retry() {
    usersDataSourceFactory.getUserLiveData().value?.retry()
}

fun listIsEmpty(): Boolean {
    return pagedUserList.value?.isEmpty() ?: true
}
fun getPagedList(): LiveData<PagedList<User>> {
    return pagedUserList
}
```

**DataSourceFactory**

```
class UsersDataSourceFactory(
private val usersService: UsersService,
private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
) : DataSource.Factory<Int, User>() {

  private val usersDataSourceLiveData = MutableLiveData<UsersDataSource>()

override fun create(): DataSource<Int, User> {
    val usersDataSource = UsersDataSource(usersService, compositeDisposable)

    usersDataSourceLiveData.postValue(usersDataSource)

    return usersDataSource
}

fun getUserLiveData() = usersDataSourceLiveData
}
```

**DataSource**

```
 class UsersDataSource(
  private val usersService: UsersService,
  private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
 ) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, User>() {


var state: MutableLiveData<State> = MutableLiveData()
private var retryCompletable: Completable? = null

override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, User>
) {

    updateState(State.LOADING)

    compositeDisposable.add(
        usersService.getUsers(0, 20)
            .subscribe({ response: List<User> ->

                updateState(State.DONE)
                val nextPageKey = response[response.size - 1].id
                callback.onResult(
                    response, null, nextPageKey
                )
            }, { t: Throwable? ->
                updateState(State.ERROR)
                setRetry(Action { loadInitial(params, callback) })

            })
    )
}

override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, User>) {
    updateState(State.LOADING)

    compositeDisposable.add(
        usersService.getUsers(params.key + 1, 20)
            .subscribe({ response: List<User> ->

                updateState(State.DONE)
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    val nextPageKey = response[response.size - 1].id
                    callback.onResult(response, nextPageKey)
                }else {
                    updateState(State.ERROR)
                    setRetry(Action { loadAfter(params, callback) })
                }

            }, { t: Throwable? ->
                updateState(State.ERROR)
                setRetry(Action { loadAfter(params, callback) })

            })
    )
}

override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, User>) {
}


private fun updateState(state: State) {
    this.state.postValue(state)
}

fun retry() {
    if (retryCompletable != null) {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            retryCompletable!!
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe()
        )
    }
}

private fun setRetry(action: Action?) {
    retryCompletable = if (action == null) null else Completable.fromAction(action)
}
}

enum class State {
   DONE, LOADING, ERROR
}
```